# When using beautifulsoup to web scrape then save to csv, I am only receiving one row of information instead of all desired rows

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

Disclaimer: I am new to coding.

I assume my issue is within my for loop, but I am not sure what to change even after browsing answered questions on stackoverflow. So, here is my code with regards to my question:

```
csv_file = open('converter_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['Category Name', 'Price'])
entries = soup.find_all('div', class_="prices")
for entry in entries:
    cat_name = entry.h3.text.strip()
    print(cat_name)
    cat_price = entry.p.text.strip()
    print(cat_price)
    csv_writer.writerow([cat_name, cat_price])
csv_file.close()
```

The above script produces "Small Breadloaf Cat" and "$105-$200/each" from the website. This is what I want, but there are more after this one. The for loop stops after retrieving one. I am seeking the name, and the corresponding price (Small Breadloaf Cat, Large GM Cat, Large Foreign Cat, etc). However my csv is only getting the very first category+price and not all of them.

```html
<div class="prices">
    <div class="price-list">
        <div class="price ">
            <a href="https://X.com/metal/small-breadloaf-cat/">
                <h3>Small Breadloaf Cat</h3>
                <p> $105-$200/each </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price ">
            <a href="https://X.com/metal/large-gm-cat/">
                <h3>Large GM Cat</h3>
                <p> $165-$256/each </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price ">
            <a href="https://X.com/metal/large-foreign-cat/">
                <h3>Large Foreign Cat</h3>
                <p> $200-$351/each </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price ">
            <a href="https://X.com/metal/xl-foreign-cat/">
                <h3>XL Foreign Cat</h3>
                <p> $350-$500/each </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price ">
            <a href="https://X.com/metal/small-gm-cat/">
                <h3>Small GM Cat</h3>
                <p> $85-$168/each </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price ">
            <a href="https://X.com/metal/small-foreign-cat/">
                <h3>Small Foreign Cat</h3>
                <p> $108-$149/each </p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Well, you're looping over the wrong collection then. You're looping over all the divs with class=prices (of which there is only one instance in the HTML sample you gave) but it seems you really need to loop over the divs with class=price within that outer div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the for loop:

```
    
for entry in entries:

    entry.find({'class': 'price'})
```

The find_all method only returns the 'prices' class whereas you want each entry in the 'price' class. So we need two finding methods.

Comment: In the original HTML it appears to have a space after that div class. (Reference: <div class="price ">) So I previously had already tried entry.find({'class': 'price '}), with no results coming from that, but removing the space after "price" did in fact work. So, I should ignore spaces in the original HTML classes; noted. Thank you!